# use scipy.integrate.simps or similar to integrate three vectors

Tags: python, scipy, calculus

I want to approximate a function that I do not have an actual analytical expression for. I know that I want to compute this integral: `integral a * b * c dx`. Pretend that I get the `a`, `b`, and `c` are from observed data. How can I evaluate this integral? Can `scipy` do this? Is `scipy.integrate.simps` the right approach?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

a = np.random.random(10)
b = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10)
c = np.random.normal(2, .8, 10)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
dx = x[1] - x[0]

print 'Is the integral of a * b * dx is ', simps(a * b, c, dx), ', ', simps(b * a, c, dx), ',', simps(a, b * c, dx), ', ', simps(a, c * b, dx), ', or something else?'
```

Comment: Why not just sum over the values (or use some trapezoidal rule)? You won't get much more precise than that anyway.

Comment: I'd like to take advantage of scipy's backend efficiency by using it's API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your setup, the correct way to integrate is either

```
simps(a*b*c, x)   # function values, argument values
```

or

```
simps(a*b*c, dx=dx)   # function values, uniform spacing between x-values
```

Both  yield the same result. Yes, `simps` is a very good choice for integrating sampled data. Most of the time it is more accurate than `trapz`.

If the data comes from a smooth function (even though you don't know the function), and you can somehow make the number of points to be 1 more than a power of 2, then [Romberg integration](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romb.html#scipy.integrate.romb) will be even better. I compared `trapz` vs `simps` vs `quad` in [this post](https://calculus7.org/2017/01/07/vectorization-of-integration/).